# pls-00103 encountered the symbol '=' when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I get the error message pls-00103 at line 3 and 5 with this part of a trigger Im trying to make. If RENDEZVOUSSTART is after or equal to 6pm (18:00 here) the price multiplicator is 1.5 and the NOTAUXHORAIRE should be 1, in all other cases, the price multiplicator is 1 and NOTAUXHORAIRE is 0.

```html
if to_char (:new.RENDEZVOUSSTART, 'HH24') >= 18 
          THEN multiplicator := 1.5 
           and :new.NOTAUXHORAIRE := 1 ;
         else multiplicator := 1 
           AND :new.NOTAUXHORAIRE := 0;
        end if;
```

Error(3,35): PLS-00103: Symbole "=" rencontré à la place d'un des symboles suivants :     . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || indicator multiset member submultiset Symbole "* inséré avant "=" pour continuer.

Thank you very much everyone! I just started to learn Sql for a business class and Im still a newbie :D

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the syntax is Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `and` is unnecessary:

```
if to_char (:new.RENDEZVOUSSTART, 'HH24') >= 18 THEN
    multiplicator := 1.5;
    :new.NOTAUXHORAIRE := 1;
else multiplicator:= 1;
     :new.NOTAUXHORAIRE := 0;
end if;
```